# Google Image Search Image URL

Tags: html

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&">
                    <input id=search type="text" name="q"> <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Google Images">
</form>
```

I try to build a simple front end to use Google image, but this `action` brings me to google search result, any idea how to i get to the results of the searched image in google image (the input)?

Comment: How about https://images.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Use `images.google.com` or `https://www.google.com/imghp?` for the action.

Option 1:

```
<form action="images.google.com">
                    <input id=search type="text" name="q"> <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Google Images">
</form>
```

Option 2:

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/imghp?">
                    <input id=search type="text" name="q"> <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Google Images">
</form>
```

Comment: It brings me to the main page of Ggl Image, is it possible to bring me to the results of the searched image (the input)?

Comment: Im not entirely sure how you would do that unfortunately. It would probably have something to do with Php maybe?

Comment: just use <form action="images.google.com/images"> and it works